# rotational springs

Tags: classical-mechanics, spring

With a normal spring, you compress it using a linear force to store energy and then it decompresses and releases the energy, again in a form of linear force. Is there a mechanical mechanism that stores energy by rotating force and releases energy by rotating force? It doesn't have to be spring operated, but I think it's the only way to work, with springs.

Comment: [*Torsion spring.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_spring)

Comment: A rotational spring still applies a linear force over distance (on the ends of the spring) to store/release work.

Comment: Your garage door opener uses the Torsion spring pointed to by @MikeDunlavey (assuming you have a garage door with an automatic opener).  These can store a great deal of energy - don't mess with them yourself!

Comment: @JonCuster Even with the garage door opener, you need a strong spring boost.  The opener isn't strong enough by itself. You aren't strong enough, either. The doors are very heavy.  There is either a torsion spring, or on very old style doors, a linear spring on each side.

Comment: @BillN - I guess I worded my comment poorly - indeed, that is what I tried to point out.  The openers are wimpy - without the spring they could not move the door at all. But, be careful with the spring - there is a lot of stored energy there!

Comment: [*My favorite example - torsion bar suspension.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_bar_suspension)

Answer (score 1):

There are four ways that I can think of to store mechanical (elastic) energy.

1. Axial Stretch ${\rm d}W = \frac{F^2}{2 E A} {\rm d}x$
2. Torsion ${\rm d}W = \frac{T^2}{2 G J} {\rm d} x$
3. Bending ${\rm d}W = \frac{M^2}{2 E I} {\rm d} x$
4. Shearing ${\rm d}W = \frac{c F^2}{2 G A} {\rm d} x$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castigliano%27s_method and last page in http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/cee201/strain-energy.pdf

A helical or spiral torsional spring actually stores energy in bending as well as in torsion (with the axial and shearing components near zero). With some simplification you can arrive at an equation like $$k=\frac{F \ell}{\theta}$$ describing the rotational stiffness of a torsion spring. As you can see (from the link below) the energy is transferred using a linear force at the ends of the spring.

See https://www.engineersedge.com/spring_torsion_calc.htm

Comment: very strong answer

Answer (score 1):

Of course! It's called a fly-wheel. It doesn't actually involve springs; rather, it stores energy by causing a large heavy disk to spin rapidly. The disk is mounted on bearings and is well-lubricated, so that friction saps energy only at a very slow rate. More modern flywheels often use magnetic bearings, eliminating friction nearly entirely, and can rotate at some 60,000 rpm. Flywheels are often used to store large amounts of energy mechanically, to be released quickly later (often by connecting the flywheel to a generator). See these pages:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel_energy_storage

Answer (score 0):

[Control moment gyros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_moment_gyroscope) , like those used on the space station can store tremendous amounts of energy and are used to create torque to change spacecraft attitude (rotation). The energy is stored by the wheel's high angular velocities, and the torque is created by tilting the wheel (pushing against the wheel's angular momentum).